# Can I use a ModelViewSet for POST and GET of a parent of self in a model in Django REST?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, parent, django-serializer

Hello I have the following structure:
class Category(models.Model):

`model.py`

```py
    """Class to represent the category of an Item. Like plants, bikes..."""
    name = models.TextField()

    description = models.TextField(null=True)

    color = models.TextField(null=True)

    # This will help to anidate categories
    parent_category = models.ForeignKey(
        'self',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
    )
```

Then I serialize it:
`serializers.py`:

```py
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for Category."""
    
    class Meta: # pylint: disable=too-few-public-methods
        """Class to represent metadata of the object."""
        model = Category
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'description', 'color', 'parent_category']
```

And I Create my endpint
`views.py`:

```py
class CategoryViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet): # pylint: disable=too-many-ancestors
    """API Endpoint to return the list of categories"""
    queryset =  Category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
    pagination_class = None
```

Well this seems to work as expected to make a post request, for example sending this:

```json
 {
    "name": "Plants",
    "description": null,
    "color": "#ef240d",
    "parent_category": 1
  }
```

But when I make a request of this I want to see the parent category and not have to do two requests. So I found from other questions that I could use an external library:
`serializer.py`

```py
from rest_framework_recursive.fields import RecursiveField
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for Category."""
    parent_category = RecursiveField(many=False)
    
    class Meta: # pylint: disable=too-few-public-methods
        """Class to represent metadata of the object."""
        model = Category
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'description', 'color', 'parent_category', 'category_name']
```

And then It seems to work:

```json
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Flowers",
    "description": null,
    "color": "#ef240a",
    "parent_category": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Plants",
      "description": "something",
      "color": "#26def2",
      "parent_category": null,
    },
  },
```

But when I try to post now it will not work as It seems to expect an object instead of just the ID which is what I would have available in my frontend:

```json
{
  "parent_category": {
    "non_field_errors": [
      "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got int."
    ]
  }
}
```

Is it possible to mix somehow this two approaches in my ModelSerializer?

Answer (score 1):

You can customise your ModelViewSet to use two serializers instead of one. For example

```
class CategoryViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
    pagination_class = None
    
    def create(self, request):
        new_category = CategoryCreateSerializer(data=request.data)
        if new_category.is_valid:
            return Response(CategoryRetrieveSerializer(new_category).data)
```